# Blazor - how to apply attribute to parent element from a component

Tags: c#, blazor

I have the following cshtml page:

```
@inherits BlazorLayoutComponent

<NavMenuToggleComponent></NavMenuToggleComponent>

<div class="main">
<div class="top-row px-4">
    <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto"><span class="col-md-1">About</span></a>
    <NavLink class="nav-link pull-right col-md-2" id="logout" href="logout">
        <span class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="col-md-1 pull-right">Logout</span>
    </NavLink>
</div>

<div class="content px-4">
    @Body
</div>
```

as you can see I have a component called NavMenuToggleComponent  who's code  is:

```
@inherits Blazor.Web.Functions.MenuFunctions

<div class="pl-4  navbar navbar-dark">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-brand main-button" title="MENU" onclick=@ToggleNavMenu>
    MENU
</button>
</div>

<div class="sidebar @(CollapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null)">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
```

I have a function on the button click event and this is declared in the MenuFunctions Class. This, function simply has :

```
public  void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    CollapseNavMenu = !CollapseNavMenu;
}
```

Now to keep it simple from this function I want to be able to add an attribute to the  element on the parent that has the class content on it. so as an example I might want this to end up as `<div class="content px-4" style="color:red">` so How would I attach the style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many choices (A service in DI, global static class, cascading value etc), but the easiest to explain is perhaps a CascadingValue.

For this, you need to wrap your div inside a CascadingValue like this

```
<CascadingValue Name="LayoutStateName" Value=@LayoutState>
    <div class="content px-4" style="color:@LayoutState.Color">
        @Body
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
```

Now, you need to define what LayoutState is, so create a new Class and inside that a property to hold whatever shared state you need.

```
public class SharedMenuState
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

In your LayoutFunctions class, add a field or property to hold the state and call it LayoutState (in this example)

```
public SharedMenuState LayoutState = new SharedMenuState;
```

So, now your MenuFunctions class can take a CascadingParameter to gain access to the LayoutState

```
[CascadingParameter(Name="LayoutStateName")] protected SharedMenuState LayoutState { get; set; }
```

And finally your button click handler can be

```
public  void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    CollapseNavMenu = !CollapseNavMenu;
    LayoutState.Colour = CollapseNavMenu ? "red" : "green"; // or whatever
}
```

I have written this from memory so please excuse naming errors.

Comment: I managed to get this to work, but I had to declare the property as static.